# Python 2.7: Error importing slate

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am having a problem using slate for Python. When I try to import the slate library, I receive this error:

`ÌmportError: cannot import name PDFDocument`

I installed slate using pip (Ubuntu 17 terminal), the exact command I used was:

`pip install slate`

Here are some things that I have tried to resolve the issue:

1. Installed PDFMiner, which slate depends on.
2. Imported all of pdfminer before attempting to import slate
3. I tried this command in the terminal:
   `pip install --upgrade --
   ignoreinstalled slate==0.3 pdfminer==20110515` but received an error that version 0.3 for slate was invalid.

I am just trying to test this simple script:

```
import slate

pdf = 'test.pdf'

with open(pdf) as f:
    doc = slate.PDF(f)

for page in doc[:2]:
    print page
```

Answer (score 2):

So, this is kind of awkward (answering my own question), but I found a solution just in case anyone else is running into the same problem.

Step 1: Uninstall pdfminer

`pip uninstall pdfminer`

Step 2: Install a specific version of pdfminer: 20110515 (this *seems* to be the last version that worked with slate)

`pip install pdfminer==20110515`